# VBA: DateDiff Year off

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following code in VBA to return the year between two dates: `DateDiff("yyyy", "10/10/1930","06/07/2008 8:30:00 AM")`
It returns **78**, but it should really be **77**.
What is going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBA's DateDiff function was not designed to track elapsed time.  That statement is simply evaluating the year.

See this msdn article, which offers a function to calculate the years elapsed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnvbadev/html/workingwithelapsedtime.asp

```
Function elapsed_years_function(first_date As Date, Optional second_date As Date = 0) As Integer
' This procedure is from http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/dnvbadev/html/workingwithelapsedtime.asp
Dim elapsed_years As Integer
If second_date = 0 Then
' Did the caller pass in a date? If not, use
' the current date.
second_date = Date
End If
elapsed_years = DateDiff("yyyy", first_date, second_date)
If second_date < DateSerial(Year(second_date), Month(first_date), Day(first_date)) Then
elapsed_years = elapsed_years - 1
End If
elapsed_years_function = elapsed_years
End Function
```

Comment: This looks like a good function, but I don't see where you found it on the linked page.

Comment: The DateSerial if condition seems about right. Would I need to do the same to calculate days, minutes, and hours?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (VB.Net)  As pointed out by @Justin, this is for VB.Net, not Visual Basic, but the implementation is most likely identical for backwards compatibility. I've referenced the relevant VBScript documentation below for completeness.

> **Larger Intervals**. If Interval is set
>   to DateInterval.Year, the return value
>   is calculated purely from the year
>   parts of Date1 and Date2. Similarly,
>   the return value for
>   DateInterval.Month is calculated
>   purely from the year and month parts
>   of the arguments, and for
>   DateInterval.Quarter from the quarters
>   containing the two dates.
>
> For example, when comparing December
>   31 to January 1 of the following year,
>   DateDiff returns 1 for
>   DateInterval.Year,
>   DateInterval.Quarter, or
>   DateInterval.Month, even though at
>   most only one day has elapsed.

Also see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhtyw595%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (VBScript):

> When comparing December 31 to January
>   1 of the immediately succeeding year,
>   DateDiff for Year ("yyyy") returns 1
>   even though only a day has elapsed.

So it's likely implemented like this, which gives **78**:

```
Year(SecondDate) - Year(FirstDate)
```

See @Ken's solution for an implementation that should work as intended.

Comment: While this appears to be true, the documentation you linked to is for the .NET DateDiff function, not the VBA one ([here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datediff-function-HA001228811.aspx)).  They probably kept the same behavior for compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you did DateDiff("yyyy", "12/31/2010", "1/1/2011") it would return 1, even though there is only a day difference.

Answer (score 0):

Working as designed:  see Remarks (larger intervals) under http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx WHICH STATES:

If Interval is set to DateInterval.Year, the return value is calculated purely from the year parts of Date1 and Date2.

When you do datediff by year the operation performed is 2008 - 1930